# Apply function to a list of network objects with different function arguments

Tags: r, igraph, lapply, mapply

I have a list of igraph network objects and a function that I want to apply to each network with a different set of function arguments for each network.

Reproducible example:

```
# network
network <- graph(c("1","2","3","4"),directed = FALSE)

# making a list of graph objects
Converted <- list(network)
List <- rep(Converted,10)

# List with different parameters (Function arguments)
Xvalues <- 1:10

# function to add x nodes to the network
AddNode <- function(network,x){

        for (i in 1:x){

                network <- network + vertex(as.character(length(V(network)) + 1)) 

        }

        return(network)
}
```

What I want is to use the function with the ith set of parameters as function arguments on the ith element of the List of networks. Of course this works with a for loop but I would really like to find a solution using lapply,mapply, map, or the like because it would make the rest of the script a lot easier to read and parallelize (the function in actual script is a lot more complex and does not involve a for loop).

Here is what I unsuccessfully tried so far:

Lapply

```
ResultList <- lapply(List,AddNode,Xvalues)
```

Mapply

```
ResultList <- mapply(AddNode,List,Xvalues)
```

Map

```
ResultList <- map(.x = List,.f=AddNode,x=Xvalues)
```

suboptimal Solution using a for loop:

```
ResultList <- list(NA)
ResultList <- rep(ResultList,10)

for (i in Xvalues){

        ResultList[[i]] <- map(.x = List[i],.f=AddNode, x = Xvalues[i])

}
```

Comment: the length of your params is shorter than your list, is that intended?

Comment: Yeah, your `List` contains 10 elements but `Xvalues` only contains 4. How are those supposed to match up during the function call?

Comment: *Of course this works with a for loop*  ... please show how it works with `for` loop. Right now you only assign a function containing a `for` loop. Please post the working solution of calling *AddNode*.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Xvalues should have been 1:10, I copypastes the wrong line from my script. Sorry for that. I´ll update my example and also add the solution using the for-loop that I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Xvalues` needs to be same length as your List, and you need the `SIMPLIFY=F` parameter in mapply:

```
Xvalues <- 1:10
ResultList <- mapply(AddNode,List,Xvalues, SIMPLIFY=F)
```